# Parsing database dump file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a database dump file. The field terminator is "\t|\t". I am trying to get the first 2 fields (tax_id and parent tax_id) using this code:

code:

```
while(my $line = <INPUT>) {   
    my ($taxid, $parentid, $rank, $embl, $div, $inherdiv, $mito, $inhermito, $gbflag, $subtree, $comment)  = split (/\|/, $line);
    $taxid =~ s/^\t$//g;  
    $parentid =~ s/^\t$//g;
    print $taxid."_".$parentid."\n";
}
```

example output:

```
69223   _       204037
69224   _       551
```

It doesnt seem to clean up the tab separators when i use the substitution function s///g. Any ideas why? Is there a better way to clean up each value from the fields

Comment: If \t is a delimiter, why are you using the "^" metacharacter?

Comment: "\t|\t" is the delimiter. I've tried to split each line with no success split("\t|\t", $line) therefore i'm splitting by | only then trying to clean up the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to parse this stuff manually, I'd try using Text::CSV.

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv->new({
    binary => 1,            # just always do this
    eol => "\n",            # end of line char
    sep_char => "|",        # separator
    allow_whitespace => 1   # Auto trim tabs and spaces when parsing
});

open my $fh, '<', $path_to_db_dump
    or die "Can't open $path_to_db_dump - $!\n";

my @headers = qw/
    taxid   parentid
    rank    embl
    div     inherdiv
    mito    inhermito
    gbflag  subtree
    comment
/;
$csv->column_names( @headers );

# skip to the place in the file where data lines live

while ( my $row = $csv->get line_hr($fh) ) {

    print "$row->{taxid}_$row->{parentid}\n";

}
```

This code could be a lot more specific if you had provided a sample of raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the full delimiter instead of just a portion of it:

```
my ($taxid, $parentid, $rank, $embl, $div, $inherdiv, $mito, $inhermito, $gbflag, $subtree, $comment)
    = split "\t\\|\t", $line;
```

Then there is no need to clean up your data afterwords.

Comment: The pipe character should be escaped.

Comment: I've tried splitting the full delimiter "\t|\t" and it seems to split on the first tab and doesn't work.

Comment: @mob is correct.  | is a special regex character, so you must escape it.

Answer (score 0):

If going with your current solution, you want to ditch the "^" metacharacter which means "starts with".

You want

```
$taxid =~ s/\t//g;
```

Ex.

```
my $str = "|\tHi\t|";
print "$str\n";
$str=~ s/\t//g;
print "$str\n";
```

Output:

```
|   Hi  |
|Hi|
```

Comment: Then those aren't tabs. You can do whitespace if you want, i.e. \s instead of \t to see if those aren't tabs

Comment: I got rid of ^ and & in my substitution function and it seems to work for both variables $taxid and $parentid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the general whitespace character match:

```
$taxid =~ s/^\s*$//g;  
$parentid =~ s/^\s*$//g;
```